# SelectedValue after updating dropdown with json/webmethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, selectedvalue, webmethod

I have a dropdown list to which items are added via a json/webmethod call - an "add new item to the box" type of solution. Now - this problem is, that if I select the new value, the `_comobox1.SelectedValue` is empty.

The controls are validated via a `RequiredFieldValdiator` so I am pretty sure that a value is indeed selected, and posted.

If I look at _comobox1.Items i even see the new item, with the correct value - any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add this value to a hidden field and read it upon post. This is by design (and for security reasons) in asp.net web forms.  I'm assuming you also turned off event validation just to enable this.

See:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/05a3e4bc-b39e-4165-b04f-c3af9332b578

Comment: Thanks - and yeah - you are right. I thought that was the solution, but did not want to do it, unless it was needed..